# Render partial EEx template in Elixir (non-Phoenix) app

Tags: elixir, templating

I have a command-line Elixir app (this is *not* a Phoenix application), and I'd like to render a partial `.eex` template inside a template called say `my_template.eex`. I have code like this:

```
EEx.eval_file("layouts/my_template.eex", title: title, body: body)
```

and inside `my_template.eex`, I'd like to render the partial template `_footer.eex`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Partial template* is a convenient way to organize templates in *Phoenix*. They are still plain old good templates and since you are not using *Phoenix*, you basically have no difference between partials and “full” templates. Just render it as you do with `my_template.eex`:

```
<%= EEx.eval_file("_footer.eex", var: value) %>
```